# How to fix If condition with rollback transaction in Trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing my homework and i'm trying to create a trigger with if condition. But that Trigger doesn't work properly.

This is for my homework. Im using Northwind Database in my training.

Our teacher has asked us to create a trigger in Products table. Her question is :

"While inserting data into a Product Table; If inserted data has the same product name in Products table, cancel this transaction and print this warn message : 'That product name has already in my table' warning'"

Here is my code:

```
create trigger AyniUrun
on products
after insert
as
begin
    declare @insertedProductName nvarchar (250) =  (select ProductName from inserted)
    if exists (select ProductName from Products where ProductName = @insertedProductName)
        begin
            print 'AYNI İSİMDE ÜRÜN VAR!'
            rollback
        end 
end
```

When I try to insert the same named product into Products Table, it gives me that message : "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.". This is what i want in this condition.

But when I try to insert a different named product into Products Table, it also gives me same message and terminates my transaction. Where did i go wrong ?

Comment: Do not try and do this in a trigger. It does not have access to the context of the situation it is used in. Instead raise an exception (duplicate value), in the calling code run the insert in a transaction and rollback on the exception. Do any logging there as well if you wish. i,e, The trigger signals an error. It is handled by the controlling logic.

Comment: Her question is wierd because the normal way of avoiding duplicaties in a table column is making a Unique index key.. Also seeing your trigger code i doubt this can be a MySQL question because MySQL does not have a ‘AS’ keyword in the trigger clause or not has a print clause for that matter so iam removing the MySQL tag

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Agreed, the reason I suggest raising an error in the trigger is that it is a general solution if the error cannot easily be detected until the data is checked. You are correct about the unique index. And that is the preferred solution in real life for this condition.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Sorry about MySQL tag, i'm very new at SQL. I tried your answer but it didnt work either and gave me the same error. I agree with you btw, this is not the optimal solution for this question. But we are still learning, therefore she asked us with that specific way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for answers. Today we solved this question in class:

```
create trigger AyniUrun
on products
after insert
as
begin
    declare @insertedProductName nvarchar (250) =  (select ProductName from inserted)
    declare @counter int = (select COUNT(*) from Products where ProductName = @insertedProductName)
    print @counter
    if @counter > 1
        rollback
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But please remember the hints you got here in the comments and answers, should you ever want to implement such a thing in "real life". Your teacher teaches utter nonsense. (But you can't help that, I know.)

Comment: @stickybit Thank you for advice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use join between inserted table and product table to determine the existence. 
Please try below-

```
   CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON products
   AFTER INSERT
   AS

    if exists (select * from products p inner join inserted i on p.name=i.name)
    begin
      rollback
      RAISERROR ('Duplicate Data', 16, 1);
   end
   go
```

Comment: ... and also check for duplicates within `inserted`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simplify the code of your trigger. 
However : as it is,  this will not do what you expect :

```
begin
    print 'AYNI İSİMDE ÜRÜN VAR!'
    rollback
    ...
```

Instead, you need to :

```
begin
    RAISERROR('AYNI İSİMDE ÜRÜN VAR!')
    rollback
    ...
```

Comment: It's `RAISERROR`, without an underscore and missing an "E". But Microsoft recommends not to use it anymore and use `THROW` instead (see [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). And `TRANSACTION` is indeed optional to `ROLLBACK`. But that `ROLLBACK [TRANSACTION]` won't be reached anyway.